# PostgreSQL: wrong sorting on Ukrainian text

Tags: postgresql, sorting

I have table with all countries on three languages: English, Russian and Ukrainian. On first two languages sorting is OK. But on Ukrainian countries' names sorting is not OK.

On first two place it stands two letters `'є'` (8th position in ABC) and `'і'` (12th position in ABC) and all next letters are sorted fine.

How to prevent this behaviour? DB encoding is utf-8.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you are on 9.1, you can add the collation to be used for sorting to your ORDER BY clause:

```
SELECT *
FROM your_table
ORDER BY your_column COLLATE "ua_UA"
```

The name of the collation depends on your operating system - not sure what the correct name for Ukraine would be. But I think you get the idea.

You might also want to read this blog entry:

http://www.depesz.com/index.php/2011/03/04/waiting-for-9-1-per-column-collation-support/

Comment: Might be a good reason to upgrade (among various other things...)

Answer (score 3):

UTF-8 doesn't know anything about "language". For alphabetical sort to make any sense to Postgres you need to [set a locale](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.3/static/locale.html). Your question doesn't mention locale at all so I'm guessing you're just sorting using whatever your default locale is (probably English or Russian).

If you are already using locales then I suggest providing details of your client / server locale settings as there may be a mistake there.

Comment: Can I set few different locales? And where to write this - I mean in configures files or I can do it in PhpPgAdmin? Won't it effect on db perfomance? Thanks!

Comment: The locale variable LC_COLLATE, which is used in sorting is set when initdb runs, using system environment variables. In other words it is set when the database is created. It can't be changed later because it would corrupt indexes which rely on consistent ordering. What that means is you need a different database for each language (at least for PostgreSQL 8.4 and below) or your own sorting function.